# How to tell LLDB to continue after a segmentation fault?

Tags: debugging, signals, lldb

Context: I am programming an interpreter for another platform, and this means that often, my program will load pointers from arbitrary integer data. When it comes to branches, I try to dereference for reading the next instruction's address immediately, so that if the address is invalid, I get the segmentation fault inside the branch instruction's method, and not some time later. This should make debugging easier.

However, this is not as helpful as I would have hoped for. When a segfault occurs there, it should be completely recoverable, since it was triggered by a dummy read, so I would like to be able to move the program's instruction pointer back to the beginning of the method and reset the segfault.

Can I tell LLDB to ignore a `SIGSEGV` that has already made it to my program? I know that I can use `process handle ...` to decide which signals make it to my program, but that does not apply to signals the process is currently handling (or rather not handling).

(If it is not possible, I guess I could still ask lldb to stop on segfaults and not pass them to the program, but I'd at least like to *know* if it's possible or not.)

Comment: wait, can't you use sigaction function (man 2)? using it, it's possible to set signal handler for this signal and make longjmp function (man3),returning to place that you want

Comment: @gekannt, yes, I can use `sigaction` to define a custom handler for `SIGSEGV`, but it would be harmful whenever the debugger is not attached. That's why I'd like to do it from the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to work around an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` to put it properly.  For instance, it sounds like you're describing the dataptr in this example program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  void (*funcptr)(void) = 0;
  int *dataptr = 0;
  puts ("about to deref dataptr");
  printf ("%d\n", *dataptr);
  puts ("about to call through f ptr");
  funcptr();
  puts ("done");
  return 0;
}
```

You'll hit the first EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `dataptr` dereference in the `printf` call.  You can change the variable to a valid value to continue execution.  The one trick here is that the variable `dataptr` lives on the stack in my `-O0` compiled example, so you need to set the *register* that is being read at this point to get past it.  Here I just use the start address of `main()` as a valid address in this program as a simple example.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x0000000100000eb6 a.out`main + 54 at a.c:7, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
-> 7      printf ("%d\n", *dataptr);

(lldb) disass -c 1 --pc
a.out`main + 54 at a.c:7:
-> 0x100000eb6:  movl   (%rcx), %esi
(lldb) reg read rcx
     rcx = 0x0000000000000000
(lldb) p dataptr
(int *) $0 = 0x0000000000000000

(lldb) p dataptr = (int*) main
(int *) $1 = 0x0000000100000e80
(lldb) reg write rcx `$1`

(lldb) c
Process 77491 resuming
-443987883
about to call through f ptr
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x0000000000000000, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    #0: 0x0000000000000000
```

Now I'm stopped because I called through a NULL function pointer.  Unwinding this takes a little extra x86_64 ABI knowledge but it's not all that hard -- set the pc to the caller's return address, pop the stack one word and you're back.

```
(lldb) reg write pc `*(unsigned long long *)$sp`
(lldb) reg write sp `$sp + 8`
(lldb) c
Process 77522 resuming
done
Process 77522 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

of course this is very by-hand tweaking here - not so easy to automate.  You could express the null function pointer deref with a python function and add an lldb command to do it easily, but the null data pointer deref requires that you know what register was being accessed - maybe some clever pattern matching of the disassembly instruction could do the same thing with some python extension for common cases.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought I did similar. Well, this works, so thank you very much for your great and descriptive answer.